# why svg animation for console.log not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<script>
  const svg = `
<svg class="box" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
  @keyframes bg {
    10% {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='200' height='200' %3E%3Cpath fill='%2300A5E0' d='M145.659,68.949c-5.101-5.208-13.372-5.208-18.473,0L99.479,97.233 L71.772,68.949c-5.1-5.208-13.371-5.208-18.473,0c-5.099,5.208-5.099,13.648,0,18.857l46.18,47.14l46.181-47.14 C150.759,82.598,150.759,74.157,145.659,68.949z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
    50% {
      background: red;
    }
    70% {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='200' height='200' %3E%3Cpath fill='%2300A5E0' d='M145.659,68.949c-5.101-5.208-13.372-5.208-18.473,0L99.479,97.233 L71.772,68.949c-5.1-5.208-13.371-5.208-18.473,0c-5.099,5.208-5.099,13.648,0,18.857l46.18,47.14l46.181-47.14 C150.759,82.598,150.759,74.157,145.659,68.949z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    }
    100% {
      background: silver;
    }
  }
  .box {
    animation: bg 2s linear infinite normal forwards;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  </style>
</svg>
`
  const text = encodeURIComponent(svg)

  console.log(
    '%c ',
    `padding: 100px 100px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,${text}"`);
</script>
</html>
```

when i set @keyframes 70%, there are two url for background-image, it will be not working, i don't know how to fix it and that's why。when i removed 70% settings，it will worked。it make me so confused。

Comment: console.log function does not support rendering complex elements like SVG animations

Comment: by the way what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need To move the class `.box` before keyframes and use `btoa` instead of `encodeURIComponent`

[Preview Result Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VFIW.png)

```
 // before 
 const text = encodeURIComponent(svg)
 console.log(
  '%c ',
 `padding: 100px 100px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,${text}"`);
  // after 
  console.log(
  '%c ',
  `padding: 100px 100px;
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(svg)}`);
```

Here is the full example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
         <title>Document</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
     <script>
         const svg = `
             <svg class="box" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" xml:space="preserve">
              <style type="text/css">
                 .box {
                     animation: bg 2s linear infinite normal forwards;
                     width: 200px;
                     height: 200px;
                  }
                  @keyframes bg {
                     10% {
                         background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='200' height='200' %3E%3Cpath fill='%2300A5E0' d='M145.659,68.949c-5.101-5.208-13.372-5.208-18.473,0L99.479,97.233 L71.772,68.949c-5.1-5.208-13.371-5.208-18.473,0c-5.099,5.208-5.099,13.648,0,18.857l46.18,47.14l46.181-47.14 C150.759,82.598,150.759,74.157,145.659,68.949z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
                      }
                      50% {
                         background: red;
                      }
                      70% {
                         background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='200' height='200' %3E%3Cpath fill='%2300A5E0' d='M145.659,68.949c-5.101-5.208-13.372-5.208-18.473,0L99.479,97.233 L71.772,68.949c-5.1-5.208-13.371-5.208-18.473,0c-5.099,5.208-5.099,13.648,0,18.857l46.18,47.14l46.181-47.14 C150.759,82.598,150.759,74.157,145.659,68.949z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
                      }
                      100% {
                          background: silver;
                      }
                  }
          </style>
        </svg>
       `
        console.log(
           '%c ',
           `padding: 100px 100px;
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(svg)}`);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: i know it's way, but i can't use it, because if i have some special character, btoa will be error and if i use btoa with encodeURIComponent, the original character will be changed.